# How to overwrite default cgroup cgconfig.conf using cgconfig.d?

Tags: linux, cgroups

The default cgroup config file cgconfig.conf provided with the libcgroup conatains:

```
mount {
    cpuset = /cgroup/cpuset;
    cpu = /cgroup/cpu;
    cpuacct = /cgroup/cpuacct;
    memory = /cgroup/memory;
    devices = /cgroup/devices;
    freezer = /cgroup/freezer;
    net_cls = /cgroup/net_cls;
    blkio = /cgroup/blkio;
}
```

I want to use something like this:

```
mount {
    cpuset = /cgroup/cpu_and_mem;
    cpu = /cgroup/cpu_and_mem;
    cpuacct = /cgroup/cpu_and_mem;
    memory = /cgroup/cpu_and_mem;
 }

group cpu_memory_high {
  cpu {
      cpu.shares = 800;
  }
  cpuset {
      cpuset.cpus="0-6";
  }
  memory {
      memory.limit_in_bytes = 5G;
  }
}

group cpu_memory_low {
 cpu {
     cpu.share = 200;
 }
 cpuset {
     cpuset.cpus="8"
 }
 memory {
     memory.limit_in_bytes = 500M;
 }
}
```

I don't want to overwrite cgconfig.conf, So I tried to use cgconfig.d with above settings in a new file abc.conf and placed it in cgconfig.d.
But these new settings didn't work for me.
Anyone have idea whats wrong with above config.

Comment: I think your question is good, but it is probably better suited for http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 2):

In order to work `/etc/cgconfig.d/` directory you have to add:

```
$CGCONFIGPARSER_BIN -L /etc/cgconfig.d/
```

*after:*

```
$CGCONFIGPARSER_BIN -l $CONFIG_FILE
```

line in `/etc/init.d/cgconfig` file.

It works on Amazon Linux at least.

Answer (score 1):

On Centos 7, it seems /etc/cgconfig.d was enabled by default, but it seems that is no longer the case on Centos 8.  Here's how I fixed it:

1. Copy the default *cgconfig* unit file to *cgconfigd.service*:

```
sudo cp /usr/lib/systemd/system/cgconfig.service \
        /etc/systemd/system/cgconfigd.service
```

2. Edit the file:

   - Change both occurrences of `-l /etc/cgconfig.conf` to `-L /etc/cgconfig.d`.
   - Under `[Unit]`, add `After=cgconfig.service`
3. Enable and start the service:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable cgconfigd
sudo systemctl start cgconfigd
```

Answer (score 0):

You have misunderstood how cgroups work. The mounts are arbitrary. Your group declarations create new directories in the mounts. There is never any need to combine subsystem directories and doing so will make it impossible to control tasks separately as they all use similar directory structures. It will more than likely cause cgroups to fail altogether.

The mounts you already have are fine, and the groups you set up will work as they are. You only need to reference the group name and the subsystem. Combining mounts will not make any difference.

See https://askubuntu.com/a/94743/170177

Comment: I see the Redhat manual does this. No idea why, probably just to be different. It's pointless.

Comment: So, even If I keep the mount points same how do I use cgconfig.d? It didn't pickup my config from abc.conf